# How to format the output based on the maximum column length

Tags: shell, unix, formatting

Formatting the output based on the maximum column length. How can I achieve this?

Shell script or any tools is fine.

Input

```
| date | ID | Typ | Actn |
| 11/29/13 | ID660011  | DP | A | 
| 11/29/13 | ID6600123  | DP | A |
```

Output

```
| date    | ID       | Typ| Actn|
| 11/29/13| ID660011 | DP | A   | 
| 11/29/13| ID6600123| DP | A   |
```

**EDIT:**

> If I use column -t, these are the errors:
>   $ column -t -s'|' -o'|'
>   input_file .feature > input_file _check.feature
>   column: illegal option -- o
>   usage: column [-tx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]
>
> $ echo $SHELL  /usr/local/bin/bash
>
> $ column -t input_file .feature > input_file _check.feature  column:
>   line too long

Comment: Any particular shell?

Comment: You can do: `column -t file`

Comment: @ScottHunter bash is preferable, but, any shell is fine

Comment: Would a couple of extra spaces hurt?

Comment: Does `column -t -s'|' -o'|'  inputfile` do what you want?

Comment: @devnull column -t is sort of working, but, not on the lengthy columns. But, with adding sed is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I was using GNU/Linux column. You're on BSD or Solaris?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I am using a Mac, sorry, didn't mention that.

Comment: @anubhava How can I increase the LINE_MAX in Unix?
"man column: BUGS
     Input lines are limited to LINE_MAX (2048) bytes in length."

Comment: Is your line width more than 2k?

Comment: @anubhava my mistake, actually no. The maximum line length on the input file is 234. Not sure, why it is giving column length too long and truncating the lines.

Comment: can you show me top output of `cat -vte file`?

Comment: @anubhava I recognized the mistake, the error occurs when the number of columns in the input file does not match which is the case for one row. Then I did a sed to replace | with @| and used column with -s '@' option. It worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On your shell terminal, try this one:

```
$ awk '
{
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
   printf("%-40s%c", $i, (i==NF) ? ORS : "")
}' FS=, file.txt
```